# How to point to the right MongoDB Repository release?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install mongo **v2.6.4**, as you can see in my repo below, it is pointing to MongoDB **2.6** Repository - after I installed it, I ended up with **v2.6.11** which is not the right release I need. I am deploying my version **2.6.4** to a new servers and would like to keep the same release for now & upgrade at later time..

How do I make sure I am using **MongoDB 2.6.4 Repository** and NOT  **v2.6.11** Repository ?

How/Where to get the repo from ?

> > here is my repo setup

$ cat mongodb-org.repo

```
[mongodb-org-2.6]
name=MongoDB **2.6** Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.. I can choose a specific version by appending the package version like so:

yum install -y mongodb-org-2.6.4 mongodb-org-server-2.6.4 mongodb-org-shell-2.6.4 mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.4 mongodb-org-tools-2.6.4

Thx.